# Fetching specific data within the quotes using regex in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am trying to fetch the plugin version from the config XML file(fread) using regex.
Using the following regex. But I am getting the entire line instead, I am just interested in the version i.e "4.3.0". Any help on how that can be achieved?

```py
(Pdb) key
'plugin="git'
(Pdb) re.findall(key+".*",fread)
['plugin="git@4.2.2">\\n    <configVersion>2</configVersion>\\n    <userRemoteConfigs>\\n      <hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>\\n
```

Comment: `re.findall(r"key\s*'(.*?)'", fread)`? `re.findall(r"key\s*'[^\d']*(.*?)'", fread)`?

Comment: key
'plugin="git'
(Pdb) re.findall(key+".*",fread)
['plugin="git@4.2.2">\\n    <configVersion>2</configVersion>\\n
re.findall(r"key\s*'[^\d']*(.*?)'", fread)
[]
@WiktorStribiżew : Its not finding anything , empty list

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most optimal regex check, but it does work: [Regexr Tester](https://regexr.com/5k13t) The link will explain how the capture works. From that just strip the string of the `@` symbol.

this would also allow for finding multiple sets if they are defined if you want a more precise check you can search for `git@` blah blah blah and return all of those then just strip the front part essentially

Comment: re.findall(key+".@*",fread)
['plugin="git@']   --- Not getting the version detail

Comment: You need to use the exact regex I linked, and strip the extra content appended, it will give the version of it at that point. I mentioned you can add the ``git@`` to specify further in case of many objects, but if you only have that then you should find one instead of using a findall